# React - how to dynamically create elements with attributes and then nest those in another element?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a table row dynamically for use in the `render` function of a React component. As far as I understand it, you can use `React.createElement` function to create the elements, but not sure how to chain together a series of dynamically generated `<td>` elements and also set their attributes. For example:

```
var cols = this.props.array_of_col_objects;
var react_col_array = [];
var row = React.createElement("tr");
for(c=0;c<cols.length;c++){
    var col = React.createElement("td");
    // how to set the attributes of this element, e.g. className, id, etc.

    react_col_array.push(col);
} 

// How do i now insert the generated column elements into the row element?
```

Comment: If you're new to React, I encourage you to use JSX instead of `createElement`. You'll have a much easier time following the documentation and sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a tr with child td's easily like this, using JSX-syntax and mapping your cols-array with `map()`-method:

```
<tr className="row">
    {cols.map(function (colData, index) {
        return <td key={index} data-some-attr={colData.someProperty}>{colData.someOtherProperty}</td>;
    })}
</tr>
```

Note `key`-attribute that's being set in mapping function, we need to specify it for elements in lists for React to be able to optimize rendering process. It should be unique and in this case we can just use index of the element in the array.

You can use that directly in `render()`-function or move it in separate function and then use it in there like this:

```
function renderTableRow () {
    return <tr> ... </tr>;
}

render () {
    return <div>{this.renderTableRow()}</div>;
}
```

---

UPDATE:

Sorry, forgot to mention that if you want to set custom attribute (not defined in HTML specification) you need to prefix it with `data-`

Comment: How would you handle creating the attributes for the element, if the attribute on the colData object might/might not be there?

Comment: if the value you pass in attribute via curly braces is null or undefined the attribute won't be set at all

Comment: and if you want to use a default value in this case you can set attribute like this: `data-attr={value ? 'is-true' : 'default-value'}`